# Telegram bot api not able to restrict user for 24 hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, bots, telegram-bot

Looking for solution to restrict chat member with `restrictChatMember()` but unfortunately it still restrict the user forever not for 24 hours.

```
const { date:joinDate } = ctx.message;

const releaseDate = moment.unix(joinDate).add(1, 'day');
ctx.telegram.restrictChatMember(
  ctx.chat.id,
  memberID,
  releaseDate,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false
);
```

Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a `moment` object back into the function, not an UNIX timestamp like the docs you quoted say:

> **`until_date`**: optional integer
>   Date when restrictions will be lifted for the user, unix time. If user is restricted for more than 366 days or less than 30 seconds from the current time, they are considered to be restricted forever.

Try

```
ctx.telegram.restrictChatMember(
  ctx.chat.id,
  memberID,
  releaseDate.unix(),
  ...
```